# Is Flask required when running an application with uWSGI?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, uwsgi

I am learning about using Flask for running a web application.  Many guides describe how to use uWSGI as a server to run a Flask app.  If uWSGI can run the application, is Flask still required along with it?

Answer (score 4):

Flask doesn't run an application, it *is* the application.  uWSGI runs applications such as those created with Flask.  Flask isn't required, but *some* application is.

WSGI is a standard defined in [PEP 3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/) that describes how a HTTP server talks to a Python application.  uWSGI implements the server side of WSGI.  Flask is a framework for creating programs that implements the application side of WSGI.

Given that WSGI is a documented standard, Flask is not required for creating a WSGI application.  uWSGI does not implement the application side, so you would still write an application separate from it and use uWSGI to serve that.  Any other WSGI framework could be used, or it could be implemented manually.

At its most basic a WSGI application is a callable that takes an `environ` dict and `start_response` function, acts on the data in the dict, calls `start_response` with status and headers, then returns the body of the response.  For example, uWSGI could serve this just as well as it could serve a Flask application.

```
def basic_application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return b'Hello, World!'
```

From the PEP:

> this should not be construed to mean that application developers will use WSGI as a web programming API! It is assumed that application developers will continue to use existing, high-level framework services to develop their applications. WSGI is a tool for framework and server developers, and is not intended to directly support application developers.

While it is possible to do, it is not advised.  There are too many things (see the PEP) that are difficult to get right and not particularly interesting or easy to implement that would be required to write anything more powerful than the example above.  Which is why frameworks like Flask exist.